# Unable to select account creation with voice in Google Actions Console

Tags: actions-on-google, account-linking

I am trying to setup my own smart devices, but of course I want the user to authorize before logging in to my application. I would rather not do it with OAuth, simply because Google Sign-in is way easier. However, this can only be enabled when you set the *Do you want to allow users to sign up for new accounts via voice?* option to `yes`. Unfotunately this option does not seem to be there in the actions console. [image]

What is the reason I can't select this? Are there extra requirements for it?

Comment: Hi Sander, how did you create this actions on google project, did you use a standard template from a tutorial? The yes option is there when I look at my default AoG project created via Dialogflow.

Comment: Hi Jordi,

I just click on New Project -> Smart Home. After that, the window as shown in the image is there.

Comment: Okay, I'm also getting the same screen now. I've looked at some post online and they show that this wasn't like this before. https://medium.com/google-developers/authenticating-smart-home-actions-for-the-google-assistant-with-auth0-b6fda3d2ee3d. It could be account linking has been changed by Google for Smart Home Actions, but I can't find any source for it

Comment: Hi,

That was exaclty the tutorial that I was following haha. And I was thinking the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Smart home actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/) do not support Google Sign-in. You can only use OAuth.

Comment: it's possible to use google signin + Auth0